# ARM NEON support in Qemu

Tags: android-emulator, arm, qemu, neon

Android emulator that comes with the Android SDK has support for NEON instruction set emulation (tested that myself).
And it's based on QEMU.

I recently tried to create a custom VM with QEMU (emulating Cortex-A9) and installed some ARMEL Linux distribution.

However, after installation `/proc/cpuinfo` is not showing `neon` in CPU features.
What trick actually Android emulator does so NEON appears to be available inside their VM?

Comment: it is either a newer version than yours or yours is configured differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These values are stored in `elf_hwcap` (see [kernel/setup.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c)).  The [vfp/vfpmodule.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/vfp/vfpmodule.c) detects `NEON` support and sets a bit in `elf_hwcap`.  Specifically via this code,

```
            /*
             * Check for the presence of the Advanced SIMD
             * load/store instructions, integer and single
             * precision floating point operations. Only check
             * for NEON if the hardware has the MVFR registers.
             */
            if ((read_cpuid_id() & 0x000f0000) == 0x000f0000) {
#ifdef CONFIG_NEON
                    if ((fmrx(MVFR1) & 0x000fff00) == 0x00011100)
                            elf_hwcap |= HWCAP_NEON;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_VFPv3
                    if ((fmrx(MVFR1) & 0xf0000000) == 0x10000000)
                            elf_hwcap |= HWCAP_VFPv4;
#endif
            }
```

The `read_cpuid_id()` is a macro for the co-processor CP15 which gets a *cpu id* bit map.  The `fmrx()` also uses another VFP co-processor register.  So the emulator you are using is not responding properly to `MRC` instructions from either co-processor register; or maybe it does not support `NEON` emulation.

Comment: So Neon not being listed in /proc/cpuinfo doesn't necessarily mean the emulation is not supported, right?

Comment: @NumberFour That is correct.  You should be careful, Linux may emulate Neon via *undefined instructions* exception. Then you would be emulating NEON under a hyper-visor.  I only see [alignment.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/alignment.c), [vfpdouble.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/vfp/vfpdouble.c), and [vfpsingle.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/vfp/vfpsingle.c) that seem to be emulating instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. You have to emulate hardware that has neon support. beaglexm has support. check this [here](http://www.cnx-software.com/2011/09/26/beagleboard-emulator-in-ubuntu-with-qemu/)